# Trying to trigger a build for a branch only when there is a checkin to that branch

Tags: git, jenkins

We have 10-15 git branches but we only want to trigger Jenkins jobs on 2 of these ("master" and "beta1").  I am using the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) for Jenkins and specifying both "master" and "beta1" in the "branches to build" section.  I am also specifying ${GIT_BRANCH} in the "Local subdirectory for repo (optional)" field.

I want to trigger the Jenkins job *only* on the master branch *only* when a checkin appears on the master branch.

I want to trigger the Jenkins job *only* on the beta1 branch *only* when a checkin appears on the beta1 branch.

I want both of these branches controlled by the same Jenkins job so that the build number will be unique between the 2 branches (if they were in 2 different jobs, the build numbers could be the same).

Currently, it seems to be triggering a job on beta1 branch for a checkin from master branch.  From the logs (Note: the change triggered as reported in the first line in the log below is from the master branch):

```
Started by remote host (IP) with note: Triggered by push of revision e4391d0049ff: "blah" to (URL) by (USER)
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Orca/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Orca/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3ae1a582
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 7e2aae6c752a16516d9f6ac48944492a4e3596d4 (origin/master)
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository (SSH)
git --version
git version 1.7.4.1
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Cleaning workspace
Resetting working tree
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/beta1
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/(BLAH)
Seen 22 remote branches
Multiple candidate revisions
Scheduling another build to catch up with Orca
Commencing build of Revision eaad42c836a87672c546d61f310cc31bf03ecb97 (origin/beta1)
Checking out Revision eaad42c836a87672c546d61f310cc31bf03ecb97 (origin/beta1)
```

Comment: Do you have the last version of Jenkins and/or the git plugin?

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this:

> specifying both "master" and "beta1" in the "branches to build" section

and you are triggering the build based on polling Git, then Jenkins is going to trigger the job when it finds changes in either of these branches. That's the intended functionality, and the configuration you're looking for is not supported to my knowledge.

I can suggest two possible solutions:

1. Use two separate Jenkins jobs. This is how we do it, and if we need to keep build numbers discrete then we just separate the build numbers by a large number. You can set the next build number to 300,000 on one of the jobs, for example.
2. Create two jobs, one that tracks each branch but doesn't actually build anything. Use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to trigger the same downstream job with the Git branch parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using the [post commit hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) of git. This might also give you a quicker start of the build than polling.

**Make the following changes to Jenkins:**

1. Ensure that you have the [Parameterized Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) installed.
2. Configure the job in question to be parameterized. Consider naming this parameter "BRANCH_TO_BULD". Consider a default value of "master"
3. Set Source Code Management to "None"
4. Disable Polling
5. In the first of the Build Steps, execute the following shell commands:

```
cd /path/to/your/workspace/SpecialJob 
git reset --hard 
git clean -f -d 
git fetch origin 
git checkout $BRANCH_TO_BUILD
```

**Make the following changes to Git:**

1. Start by navigating to the hooks directory in the root of your **origin** git repository
2. Rename post-receive.sample to post-receive
3. Edit the contents of the file to include the following (change MyJenkinsBox & MySpecialJob):

```
echo  
# if you want to send some fancy text to the committer's console output.
echo Post Receive Hook  
echo  
while read oldrev newrev refname  
do  
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)  
    # only build for master  
    if [ "master" == "$branch" || "beta1" == "$branch" ]; then  
        # more valuable feedback to the committer's console output  
        echo Building MySpecialJob job on Jenkins. Branch = $branch  
        echo  
        curl -s -X POST http://MyJenkinsBox:8080/job/MySpecialJob/buildWithParameters?BRANCH_TO_BUILD=$branch  
        echo  
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old post, but if still someone looking for this issue, here is how to solve it.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22794

Few recent comments on the Jenkins website related to how to solve it on EC2, but I havent tested those on AWS myself, hence some area to explore if it works in your respective scenario or not.